# executing various steps in cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-build

I want to execute 3 steps in the same cloud build yaml but I get this error:
ERROR while parsing a block mapping

```
steps:

- name: 'git image'
  args: [args]
  id: 'Clone Repository'

# Compile the pipeline.
- name: 'custom image'
  entrypoint: 'python'
  args: [args]
  
  id: 'Compile Pipeline'

artifacts:
    objects:
      location: '$_GCS_LOCATION'
      paths: ['path']


- name: 'custom image'
  entrypoint: 'python'
  args: ['args']
          
  id: 'Trigger Pipeline'

logsBucket: 'project-bucket-logs'

serviceAccount: 'service-account'
```

I get the error in the last:

- name
  expected , but found '-'

Comment: You have a different indent after `artifacts:` so this `yaml` file is not parsed the way you'd like. Try to change it according to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/store-build-artifacts)

Answer (score 0):

You have a different indent after `artifacts:` so this `yaml` file is not parsed the way you'd like. This part should look like this:

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: '$_GCS_LOCATION'
    paths: ['path']
```